# Intrinsic code optimisation hints

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics, avx

I am learning AVX intrinsic usage and the question is how to optimize the following code. The way I ported it to intrinsic work but i have the bad feeling that it goes much easier and more efficient.

c++ pseudo code version

```
float min_value = FLOAT_MAX;
float result_p = 0;
for loop
{
  float u = ....

  if(u > 0.0f || u < 1.0f)
    continue;

  float p = ...
  float t = ....

  if(t < min_value)
  {
    min_value = t;
    result_p = p;
  }
}
```

i optimized this with the following code:

```
int resultMask = 0
float min_value = FLOAT_MAX;
float result_p = 0;
for loop
{
  __m256 u = ....

  if(u.m256_f32[0] < 0.0f || u.m256_f32[0] > 1.0f) resultMask &= 0xFE;
  if(u.m256_f32[1] < 0.0f || u.m256_f32[1] > 1.0f) resultMask &= 0xFD;
  if(u.m256_f32[2] < 0.0f || u.m256_f32[2] > 1.0f) resultMask &= 0xFB;
  if(u.m256_f32[3] < 0.0f || u.m256_f32[3] > 1.0f) resultMask &= 0xF7;
  if(u.m256_f32[4] < 0.0f || u.m256_f32[4] > 1.0f) resultMask &= 0xEF;
  if(u.m256_f32[5] < 0.0f || u.m256_f32[5] > 1.0f) resultMask &= 0xDF;
  if(u.m256_f32[6] < 0.0f || u.m256_f32[6] > 1.0f) resultMask &= 0xBF;
  if(u.m256_f32[7] < 0.0f || u.m256_f32[7] > 1.0f) resultMask &= 0x7F;

  if(resultMask == 0)
    continue;

  __m256 p = ...
  __m256 t = ....

  if(resultMask & 0x01) if(t.m256_f32[0] < min_value) {min_value = t.m256_f32[0]; result_p = p.m256_f32[0];}
  if(resultMask & 0x02) if(t.m256_f32[1] < min_value) {min_value = t.m256_f32[1]; result_p = p.m256_f32[1];}
  if(resultMask & 0x04) if(t.m256_f32[2] < min_value) {min_value = t.m256_f32[2]; result_p = p.m256_f32[2];}
  if(resultMask & 0x08) if(t.m256_f32[3] < min_value) {min_value = t.m256_f32[3]; result_p = p.m256_f32[3];}
  if(resultMask & 0x10) if(t.m256_f32[4] < min_value) {min_value = t.m256_f32[4]; result_p = p.m256_f32[4];}
  if(resultMask & 0x20) if(t.m256_f32[5] < min_value) {min_value = t.m256_f32[5]; result_p = p.m256_f32[5];}
  if(resultMask & 0x40) if(t.m256_f32[6] < min_value) {min_value = t.m256_f32[6]; result_p = p.m256_f32[6];}
  if(resultMask & 0x80) if(t.m256_f32[7] < min_value) {min_value = t.m256_f32[7]; result_p = p.m256_f32[7];}
}
```

All that "if" are ugly but i cant find another solution. Some one knows how can change this? I cant really believe that this is the best that can be done.

Thx

Comment: Welcome! This is not an actual problem suitable for stack overflow. For code reviews use the proper place [codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No, it's not the best.  Try using `_mm256_cmp_ps` to perform 8 comparisons in a single instruction.  (You'll need one for the low limit and one for the high limit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to try is auto-vectorization. To do this you need to enable auto-vectorization and AVX e.g. with GCC `gcc -O3 -mavx`.  But if you really want to do this with intrinsics you could try something like this:

```
__m256 min_value8 = _mm256_set1_ps(FLT_MAX);
__m256 result_p8  = _mm256_setzero_ps();
__m256 one        = _mm256_set1_ps(1.0);

for(int i=0; i<n; i+=8) {
    //__m256 u8 = _mm256_loadu_ps(&u[i]);
    __m256 u8 = ...
    __m256 t1 = _mm256_cmp_ps(u8, _mm256_setzero_ps(), 2); // u <= 0
    __m256 t2 = _mm256_cmp_ps(one, u8, 2);                 // 1 <= u
    __m256 t3 = _mm256_or_ps(t1,t2);
    if(_mm256_testz_ps(t3,t3)) continue;
    //at least one entry in u8 has u<=0 or u>=1 
    __m256 p8 = ...
    __m256 t8 = ...

    __m256 mask = _mm256_cmp_ps(t8, min_value8, 1);        // t < min_value
    //min_value8 = _mm256_or_ps(_mm256_and_ps(mask,t8), _mm256_andnot_ps(mask,min_value8));
    //result_p8  = _mm256_or_ps(_mm256_and_ps(mask,p8), _mm256_andnot_ps(mask,result_p8));
    min_value8 = _mm256_blendv_ps(min_value8, t8, mask);
    result_p8  = _mm256_blendv_ps(result_p8,  p8, mask);
}
float tmp1[8], tmp2[8];
_mm256_storeu_ps(tmp1, min_value8);
_mm256_storeu_ps(tmp2, result_p8);
float min_value = tmp1[0];
float result_p = tmp2[0];
for(int i=1; i<8; i++) {
    if(tmp1[i]<min_value) {
        min_value = tmp1[i];
        result_p = tmp2[i];
    }
}
```

this assumes that the iterations are independent i.e. that `p8` and `t8` don't depend on `min_value8`.

Edit:

I was bothered by the following code

```
__m256 mask = _mm256_cmp_ps(t8, min_value8, 1);
min_value8 = _mm256_or_ps(_mm256_and_ps(mask,t8), _mm256_andnot_ps(mask,min_value8));
result_p8  = _mm256_or_ps(_mm256_and_ps(mask,p8), _mm256_andnot_ps(mask,result_p8));
```

one line could be simplified to:

```
min_value8 = _mm256_min_ps(t8, min_value8); //probably faster
```

However, using `min` in some sense calculates the mask again. A better solution is to blend with the mask

```
_m256 mask = _mm256_cmp_ps(t8, min_value8, 1);
min_value8 = _mm256_blendv_ps(min_value8, t8, mask);
result_p8  = _mm256_blendv_ps(result_p8,  p8, mask);
```

Comment: Autovectorization isn't likely to work with a `continue;` statement in the loop body.  Perhaps if just the final assignment were conditional.

Comment: @BenVoigt, in that case I'm glad I gave a solution (untested) using intrinsic :-)